# Openwhisk Action level Concurrency limit

Tags: concurrency, serverless, openwhisk

So i am new to Openwhisk and i am trying some stuff for various experiments i want to perform. I am trying to create a web action with a concurrency limit > than the default which is 1. As far as i understood this can happen by typing wsk action create <action_name> function.js --concurrency 2 --web true, although this provides an error and the action is not created. Im currently using the standalone run for OW. Any insights on the matter?

*error: Unable to create action '0': The request content was malformed:
requirement failed: concurrency 2 exceeds allowed threshold of 1 (code 5uCNnpmwwDzMMgkWu33UW9o0zCfVH4FQ)

**the action name i used for this example is "0"

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to set the system-level concurrency limits to be greater than 1. If you've deployed OpenWhisk via Kubernetes, then you can just modify the `mycluster.yaml` file.

[This here](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/helm/openwhisk/values.yaml#L85) is the relevant part of the configuration. Simply set those values to be greater than one. For example:

```
concurrency:
    min: 1
    max: 10
    std: 1
```